# How to find an item in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to find the following item using Selenium. The value of the class changes whenever there is a change. This is inside a complex page (multiple iframes, and other items loaded dynamically). The only unique id is `itemid`, which is dynamic value and `title` combination. If I click on this Action, am getting another new set of complex items. I am new to Selenium. How to do that?

HTML:

```
<td itemid="xxyyy.as123" title="Actions" nowrap="" class="text-button">Actions&nbsp;<img src="../row.gif"></td>

<td itemid="xxyyy.as123" title="Actions" nowrap="" class="text-button button-active">Actions&nbsp;<img src="../row.gif"></td>

<td itemid="xxyyy.as123" title="Actions" nowrap="" class="text-button button-hover">Actions&nbsp;<img src="../row.gif"></td>
```

The code I tried:

1. Find by Xpath

   ```
   var element=driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[id='pageContent']/iframe/#document/ht‌ml/frameset/frame[name='detailsDisplay']/#document/html/body/form[name='tableForm‌']/div[id='divToolbarContainer']/div[id='divToolbar']/div[1][class='toolbar']/tab‌​le/tbody/tr/td[title='Actions']"));
   ```
2. Find by Link Text

   ```
   var element = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Actions"));
   ```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Until you switch to correct frame, you cannot perform any action on element.

Comment: This page is having around 10 iframes, and other elements. How do I get the right frame?

Comment: Are frames change dynamically?

Comment: Under which iframe, the element that you are trying to click comes? is that static atleast?

Comment: Enter web page is dynamically updated.

Comment: is it possible to share the website link?

Comment: Its an internal link. Let me create the structure so that I can update/share.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170391/discussion-between-dineshkumar-ponnusamy-and-pradeep-hebbar).

Comment: That would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to achieve it, by using the frame names.

```
 driver.SwitchTo().Frame("content").SwitchTo().Frame("detailsDisplay");                        
 var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"divToolbar\"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]"));
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 By.CssSelector("td[title="Actions"]");
 By.CssSelector("td[itemid="xxyyy.as123"]");
 By.CssSelector("td[itemid="xxyyy.as123"][title="Actions"]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Dynamic CSS Selector.

For Example:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("td[itemid$="xxyyy."]")).Click();
```

Note: In dynamic Elements, there is always a part of locator wich is fixed. we need to generate the locator using this part.

1. If fixed part is at starting - Use caret character (^)
2. If fixed part is at Middle - Use asterisk (*)
3. If fixed part is at End - Use dollar sign ($)

Comment: Its full of numbers. so no clue.